# Converting a file directory strutute to JSON iusing jQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, regex, json

I've an **INPUT** that is of the form of a jquery variable.

```
./Simple Root/
./Root 1/Child 1/
./Root 1/Child 2/
./Thumbs.db
./timepass
```

I would like to convert it into a neat **JSON** structure like (**Update** : Here is a JSON structure that I would like to convert http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)

```
'data' : [
       'Simple root node',
       {
         'text' : 'Root node 2',
         'state' : {
           'opened' : true,
           'selected' : true
         },
         'children' : [
           { 'text' : 'Child 1' },
           'Child 2'
         ]
      }
    ]
```

**NOTE:** I havn't mentioned all the cases where the root itself has standalone children,nested children and so on. Basically, the slashes '\' would determine all that.

I wasn't able to think of any solution apart from the regex matcher

```
var patt1 = /^[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/?/i;
```

Can someone please guide me

Comment: It is not clear how your INPUT correlates to your desired OUTPUT.  Please recheck your question and fix errors.  Please be more specific when possible.

Comment: The question is quite clear. I have variable.I want to process it into a JSON structure as above.

Comment: I am not familiar with a file directory structure being a jQuery variable.  Your input has a `Root 1`, but your output has a `Root node 2`.  This does not make sense to me.  To get your question seen, I suggest setting a bounty.